# sp update whole table instead of particular ID

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

my query is:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[AddUpdate] ---212,'pp','en-US'
@MID int,
@LPName nvarchar(250),
@CCode nvarchar(50) 
AS
BEGIN
    IF(EXISTS(SELECT MID FROM [dbo].[MC] WHERE MID=@MID))
        BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[MC]
        SET LPName=@LPName
            ,CCode=@CCode
        WHERE MID=MID
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        Insert [dbo].[MC]
        (MID,LPName,CCode)
        values
        (
        @MID,@LPName,@CCode)
        END
END
```

but instead of update particular id which was given its update a whole table.What is my mistake.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Update to :

```
 UPDATE [dbo].[MC]
        SET LPName=@LPName
            ,CCode=@CCode
        WHERE MID=@MID
```

Comment: sorry D:) unable to understand.please clear the things.Thanks.